# Java - merge duplicate key and remove duplicate value from map

Tags: java, collections

I have map which contains duplicate values. Like this :

```
{
"GROUP-A": {
    "groupname": "name1",
    "valuename": [
        "value1",
        "value2"
    ]
},
"GROUP-B": {
    "groupname": "name2",
    "valuename": [
        "value1",
        "value2"
    ]
},
"GROUP-C": {
    "groupname": "name2",
    "valuename": [
        "value2",
        "value3"
    ]
}
}
```

And I want to merge values of same groupname keys and then remove duplicate values from valuename key.
so final map would look Like this :

```
{
"groupname": "name1",
"valuename": ["value1", "value2"]
}, {
"groupname": "name2",
"valuename": ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
}
```

Bean is created for groupname and valuename field.

I have map which returns me String(e.g GROUP-A) as key and bean as value.

Comment: Can you post your attempts? And FYI there are no duplicate keys in the json you provided otherwise it wouldn't be a valid json.

Comment: I have edited the question. please find details.

Comment: @Jay you can post your code, if you have tried anything